# Is there any way I can access Admin API(GraphQL) in theme.liquid file using JavaScript(<script>...<script>)?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am trying to fetch products by 'SKU', which is only possible using Admin API. I need to inject a JavaScript code snippet into theme.liquid file. Can I achieve this via JavaScript only? So far my code looks something like this:

```
<script>
const query = `{
  productVariants(first: 1, query: "sku:<SKU>") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        price
        product {
          title
          description
          featuredImage {
            id
            originalSrc
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`;
const STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
const GRAPHQL_URL = 'https://<my-store>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-01/graphql.json';
const GRAPHQL_BODY = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'headers': {
    'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  'body': JSON.stringify({ query })
}
fetch(GRAPHQL_URL, GRAPHQL_BODY)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
</script>
```

I am not very well familiar with Shopify and Shopify's APIs(Storefront, Admin). I tried every possible way but reached dead end. I would really appreciate if someone can redirect me to right resources. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks loosely like the code from the docs here: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-with-oauth

Two issues, really:

1. in this line:

```
'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN,
```

you need be using a token which you get *after* you request it from

```
https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token
```

the bigger issue, though, is:

2. to do so only through the theme code, you would ultimately have to expose your secret keys via the front end code, which is going to be a security risk. The technically correct way to use the Admin API would either be to set up a server that runs an embedded app and store those keys in a `.env`  file there.